# How to design a referral code system in python flask sqlalchemy and postgresql

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm a bit of a database noob. I'm using flask sqlalchemy and postgresql to design a user system on a website, where each user has a unique, not null referral code. Other users can each use a single referral code, and when they do, both the owner and the user of the code receive some benefits. I'm wondering what the best way to design this is. A many to many relationship?

What I'm currently doing on the user table (other columns like email/password omitted) is:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    referral_code = db.relationship('Refcodes', backref='owner', uselist=False)
    referrals = db.relationship('Referrals', backref='user', uselist=False)
```

And on the 'refcodes' and 'referrals' table:

```
class Refcodes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'refcodes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, unique=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    referrals = db.Relationship('Referrals', backref='code')

class Referrals(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'referrals'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('refcodes.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

I haven't tested it yet since I'm still designing the login/registration page, but my question is if there is some sort of best practice/exact method for similar problems. Apologies for the bad English and the possibly vague/confusing initial questions and thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: If "each user has a unique, not null refferal [sic] code" then why do you need a separate `refcodes` table when you could simply store the referral code for each user in the `user` table? (Also note the correct spelling of "referral".)

Comment: Why do you want to use a Many to Many relationship if `many` users can use `one` referral! I would suggest to use a Many to One relationship.

Comment: @rfkortekaas yes i understand, however how do I implement that? Do I still use the 3 tables or do i use the other suggestion and keep the code in the user table? Thanks for the reply

Comment: With many to one relationships you don’t need the association table as the data can be stored in of the other tables. You can also use a `self-referential` Many to One relationship where you can store all the data in the `User` table.